# Why add a distribution management in POM if Jenkins already knows about it

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, wso2, continuous-deployment

Pretty much what the title say.

I am trying to build a CI/CD for WSO2. While following this tutorial:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationCloud/Implement+Continuous+Integration+and+Deployment+with+Jenkins

It don't say anything about adding a DistributionManagement on the POM and it even has a special POM configuration section, but nevertheless, jenkins is throwing a

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project HelloWorld: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
```

So, if jenkins already has the repo URL, the branch and the github, and the POM has a deploy goal that should deploy to a URL:

1) why do I need the Distribution Management?

2) Can I point it to any location like my file system or do I have to point it to the cloud I actually want to deploy to?

Answer (score 0):

according to maven documentation you can upload your build artifact directly to a server with maven using the tag distributionManagement

https://maven.apache.org/pom.html

the important part is the url tag. you can use scp or sftp (maybe other protocols)

scp://user:password@serverUrl/var/some/directory

I would recommend to test locally the command deploy and when you are sure it works, use jenkins.

---

If you want to make a state of the art jenkins job, I would recommend to use jenkins pipeline, execute maven with sh command and publish to a server using ssh steps provided by ssh-steps-plugin

Comment: Thank you, yeah I've being doing that, the job is currently hanging on the fact that the WSO2 API don't seem to work all that well. I still find it weird that I am REQUIRED to have a distributionManagement even though it has nothing to do with actually building or uploading the artifacts to someplace